# most recent timestamp in LevelDB

Tags: database, key-value, leveldb

I’m using LevelDB as a database for a project I’m working on. My key format looks like users!5!pages:1682795409. Thereby "!" serves as separator and the last part of the key is a timestamp. In the example above a new page for user 5 will be added with the creation timestamp of the page. What is the most efficient way to the get the latest page for user 5 using LevelDB?

Cheers